# Access function member variable from member function

Tags: javascript, closures, this

Foo is a function with a public member called list. It has a public member function called setList. I want to be able to edit list from setList. Can I do that? I've attempted a few things, but I haven't been able even to access list from inside setList.

```
var Foo = function Foo() {

    this.list = ["a", "b", "c"];

    this.setList = function(data) {
        // Attempt 1
        console.log(list); // Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
        // Attempt 2 
        console.log(this.list); // undefined
        // Attempt 3
        console.log(Foo.list); // undefined
    }
}
```

I'm still figuring JS out, so please forgive me if I've called something by the wrong name.

Comment: How are you calling this code? Also, why are you using a named closure as the constructor?

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by *how the function is called*. Without knowing how you call `setList` it's impossible for us to help you properly. Assuming you do everything else right, `this.list` should work. Maybe have a look at [MDN - Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're creating instances with `Foo`:

```
function Foo()
{
    this.list = ["a", "b", "c"];

    this.setList = function(data) {
        this.list = data;
    }
}

var x = new Foo();
console.log(x.list); // a,b,c
x.setList([]);
console.log(x.list); // empty array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a prototype which will yield the same results. I could explain reasons why sometimes you may want to use a prototype, but this link provides good information on that subject http://thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/

```
function Foo(){
  this.list = [1,2,3];
}

Foo.prototype = {
  setList: function(data){
    this.list = data;
  }
};

var x = new Foo();
x.setList(['hello', 'hi']);
console.log(x.list);
```

this will log the array passed into x.setList which is ['hello', 'hi'] showing that list was update.